# Python re.compile curly quotes issue

Tags: python, regex

I'm currently writing an application that uses a framework to match certain phrases, currently it is supposed to match the following regex pattern:

```
Say \"(.*)\"
```

However, I've notices that my users are complaining about the fact that their OS sometimes copies and pastes 'curly quotes' in, what ends up happening is that users provide the following sentence:

```
Say "Hello world!" <-- Matches
Say “Hello world!” <-- Doesn't match!
```

Is there any way I can tell Python's regular expressions to treat these curly quotes the same as regular quotes?

---

## Edit:

Turns out you can very easily tell Python to read your Regular Expression with a unicode string, I changed my code to the following and it worked:

```
u'Say (?:["“”])(.*)(?:["“”])'

# (?:["“”])    <-- Start non-capturing group, and match one of the three possible quote typesnot return it
# (.*)         <-- Start a capture group, match anything and return it
# (?:["“”])    <-- Stop matching the string until another quote is found
```

Comment: do you mean ignore, or treat the same as the straight quotes?

Comment: @ShadowFlame Treat it as the same thing, esentially

Comment: can you post the current match that you are using, or a code sample ready-to-use ? and the python version

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could just include the curly quotes in the regex:

```
Say [\"“”](.*)[\"“”]
```

As something you can replicate in the Python repl, it's like this:

```
>>> import re
>>> test_str = r'"Hello"'
>>> reg = r'["“”](.*)["“”]'
>>> m = re.search(reg, test_str)
>>> m.group(1)
'Hello'
>>> test_str = r'“Hello world!”'
>>> m = re.search(reg, test_str)
>>> m.group(1)
'\x80\x9cHello world!\xe2\x80'
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to Kyle's answer you can prepare string to your current regex by replacing curly quotes:
`string.replace('“', '"').replace('”', '"')`

Comment: As much as I would like to, I'm using a third party library which internally uses `re.compile` somewhere, which means I can't access the string  before it is matched

Comment: So it means that you can access to string only after it matches. And what happens if it doesn't?

Comment: I just won't be able to know a user entered that text, which is why it's such a problem the pattern doesn't match